# How to get image (mediaFile) from image storage path (File.path)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have multiple local storage image path which is stored in sqlite and I have to upload these image on one click.
I have a string image path but I am not sure about how to use this.
I have store image path userinfo.FileName_LHSPic to list and now I want to get image and upload to server.

FileNameUpload userinfo = new FileNameUpload();

```
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
            {
                CompressionQuality = 50,
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
            });

            userinfo.FileName_LHSPic = file.Path;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use 'file' and turn it into a byte array, and store that in your database.
When it's time to upload, stream the byte array to the server (as part of a wider scoped class), and decode the file at the server end.